# how to get javascript class properties list

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, properties

I have javascript this class :

```js
class Student {
    constructor(name, birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    get age() {
        return 2018 - this.birthDate;
    }

    display() {
        console.log(`name ${this.name}, birth date: ${this.birthDate}`);
    }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames.call(Student));
```

I want to get properties list names. I tried to use something like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames.call(Student)
```

But it doesn't work. what should I get in this example is name and birthDate only. without other methods or getters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` wrong. You don't need to use `call` on it, you just call it.* And you need to pass an instance of `Student`; the class object itself doesn't have any properties. The properties are created in the constructor, and nothing can tell you what properties the instance will have from looking at the class object.

```js
class Student {
    constructor(name, birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    get age() {
        return 2018 - this.birthDate;
    }

    display() {
        console.log(`name ${this.name}, birth date: ${this.birthDate}`);
    }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Student));
```

* If anything, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames.call(Object, new Student)` does what you want, but that's nonsensical.

Comment: Thank you very much. it works fine ^_^. I've been trying about two hours without any result. But now I understand my problem. I must use instance of class, not the class itself. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: this won't work for private properties